# how to compress image using imagemagick + command line string + php?

Tags: php, imagemagick

how to compress image using imagemagick + command line string + php?

please see my codes bellow:

```
<?php 
    /* 
        i want to use comand line to compress image in php
        this code bellow works in cmd but does not works in php
    */

    // in cmd type and run is ok
    // convert -strip -quanlity 75% 0.jpg 00.jpg

    // in php does not works
    shell_exec('convert -strip -quanlity 75% 0.jpg 00.jpg');
    // or
    exec('convert -strip -quanlity 75% 0.jpg 00.jpg');

    // but this is ok:
    exec('convert -strip 0.jpg 00.jpg');

    // why?


 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percent symbol will need to be [escaped](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) on Window's command prompt. This is because the of "[Parameter Extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)" functionality defined by the `%` character. To escape it, use double percent `%%`. Also, I believe you want to use `-quality`, as `-quanlity` is not defined in [Command-Line Options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php).

```php
exec('convert -strip -quality 75%% 0.jpg 00.jpg');
```